# Boost XML parser c++

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I'm trying to use

`BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v,pt.get_child(""))
        m_modules.insert(v.second.data());`

but I get this Error- `error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token"`

How can i Fix it?

Comment: You must quote the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out on a limb

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
```